# GCD of two whole complex numbers GCD(5-3i,7+i) in Z[i]

Tags: complex-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

I want to find GCD for two numbers, the problem is, that I dont know how.
I have two numbers **5-3i** and **7+i** in Z[i].
I know, that Euklidean algorithm should work somehow, but I am not really sure, how to do it.
If i divide the two numbers I have **(16+13i) / 17**, but I dont know how to proceed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GCD of Gaussian Integers $\text{gcd}(4, 36+18i)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3712200/gcd-of-gaussian-integers-textgcd4-3618i)

Comment: This works as well, thank you.

Comment: BTW, $$(1+i)(5-3i)-(7+i)=1+i$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use factorizations $5-3i=(1-i)(4+i)$ and $7+i = (1-i)(3+4i)$. Note that $(4+i)(4-i)=17$ and $(3+4i)(3-4i)=25$ are coprime over $\mathbb Z$, hence $\mathbb Z[i]$ as well. Therefore their gcd is $(1-i)$ up to a unit.

Comment: Oh, that is easier than using Euklidean algorithm. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more simpler solution, check the solution by @Just a user.

$f(5 - 3i) = 5^2 + 3^2 = 25 + 9 = 34$, and $f(7 + i) = 7^2 + 1^2 = 50$
Note that $GCD(34, 50) = 2$, thus any common divisor of the aforementioned Gaussian integers must also divide 2.

Since 2 can be factorized into $(1 + i)(1 - i)$, and $(1 + i) = i(1 - i),$ thus $GCD(5 - 3i, 7 + i) = (1 - i) (or \:\:1 + i)$.

This is clearly true, since:
$$(5 - 3i) = (4 - i^2) +(i-4i) = (1 - i)(4 + i),$$
and
$$(7 + i) = (3 - 4i^2)+(4i-3i)=(1 - i)(3 + 4i)$$

Comment: Thanks, that is another interesting solution.

Comment: $1+i$ and $1-i$ are equivalent because their quotient $\frac{1+i}{1-i}=i$ is a unit in $\mathbb Z[i]$. As $2$ is not their gcd, their gcd must be either $1+i$ or $1$ for $1+i$ is a prime element of $\mathbb Z[i]$.

Comment: @Just a user ok, will edit.